# Django how can I query only the records which exactly fullfill the filter condition in a Many-to-one condition

Tags: django, many-to-one

I have the following models:

```
class McMbData(models.Model):
lastname      = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True) 

class Visits(models.Model):
mcmbdata_id   = models.ForeignKey(McMbData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name      = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True) 
signe_in  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I only want to get the records of Visits where signe_in =True

Here is what I have tried:

```
McMbData.objects.filter(visits__signe_in = False)
```

So I get all McMbData entries where the condition is fulfilled at least once:

Lastname: Mutermann
Visits: Bears,True - Renegade,False - Hollywood,False

I only want to get the entries of visits which are true. Like this:

Lastname: Mutermann
Visits: Bears,True

Comment: Oh my description is wrong: "visits__signe_in = True" is right.

Answer (score 1):

you only need signe_in=True Visits for any McMbData object you can override the prefetch queryset.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


McMbData.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'visits_set', queryset=Visits.objects.filter(signe_in=True)
    )
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
McMbData.objects.filter(visits__signe_in = True)
```